# No route to host over direct ethernet, but nmap finds the machine

Tags: networking

I am connected by Ethernet to a device which I'm trying to ssh into.

To do this, I edited the Wired Connection on Ubuntu as static ip 10.11.0.2, netmask 255.255.255.0. This is the ifconfig for my ethernet device (which I configured manually):

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <snip snip...>
          inet addr:10.11.0.3  Bcast:10.11.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2560 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:98361 (98.3 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f1200000-f1220000
```

When I try

```
ssh root@10.11.0.2
```

I get 'No route to host'. But `sudo nmap -p22 10.11.0.0/24` outputs

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-03 08:04 CEST
Nmap scan report for 10.11.0.2
Host is up (0.0024s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
MAC Address: {correct MAC address DOES show up but I'm ommiting it}

Nmap scan report for 10.11.0.3
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

How can this be? This is the output from `trace -n` for the device if that helps

```
10.11.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

Comment: I installed tshark to see what was going on and the device I'm trying to connect to responds with "Who has 10.11.0.3?" to some crazy MAC address.

Comment: Check TCP wrappers in the remote machine once.

Comment: I can't do anything with the remote machine right now :)

Comment: Justs to be clear. port `22` is filtered on `10.11.0.2` so you won't be able to ssh to it if the remote IP is 10.11.0.2.  What part don't you understand?

Comment: I didn't understand how it can show up in the port scan but not respond to pings. But I understand now that it is because it has no way of linking the IP of the request to an actual MAC address. But I assigned it 10.11.02 myself using the 10.11.0.3 machine, so it's still really counter-intuitive to me how it can't recognize it.

Comment: That systems has most likely an IP firewall but doesn't firewall ARP requests. So `ping` (ICMP is over IP) or ssh (TCP is over IP) fails, but `arping` would succeed, because it's using the ARP protocol. This can be seen only because the device is in the same LAN